# Laravel delete by Id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sql-delete

Hey Im trying to delete a record in laravel but I get this error: Undefined variable: row (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\laravel\resources\views\admin\addEmployee.blade.php) at this row :  `<form action="/deleteEmployee/{{ $row->id }}" method="POST">`

Here is full HTML code
What might be possibly going wrong?

```
     <tbody>
         <!-- Displaying all the employees from the database -->
        @foreach($users as $user)
        @if($user->is_admin !== 1)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$user->name}} </td>
          <td>{{$user->email}} </td>
          <td>{{$user->salary}} $</td>
          <td>{{$user->department}} </td>
          <td>
              <a href="/editEmployee{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-success">EDIT</a>
          </td>
          <td>
              <form action="deleteEmployee/{{ $row->id }}" method="POST">
              {{csrf_field()}}
              {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
              </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
    class DashboardController extends Controller
{
   //Add employee function in admin dashboard
   public function addEmployee()
   {
       $users = User::all();
       return view('admin.addEmployee')->with('users',$users);
       //return view('adminHome');
   }

   public function editEmployee(Request $request, $id)
   {
      $users = User::findOrFail($id);
      return view('admin.editEmployee')->with('users',$users);
       //return view('adminHome');
   }

   public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
   {
    $users = User::find($id);
    $users -> name = $request -> input('name');
    $users->email = $request->input('email');
    $users->salary = $request->input('salary');
    $users->department = $request->input('department');
    $users->update();

    return redirect('admin/addEmployee')->with('status','Employee record is updated');
   }

   public function deleteEmployee( $id)
   {
      $users = User::findOrFail($id);
      $users -> delete();

      return redirect('addEmployee')->with('status','Employee record is deleted');
   }

}
```

Route

```
Route::delete('/deleteEmployee/{id}','Admin\DashboardController@deleteEmployee');
```

Comment: check if $row is set before using

Comment: Can you show the controller method which loads this `addEmployee` view?

Comment: I just updated with the full controller

Comment: Do you have that `form` element inside of a foreach loop?

Comment: yes I justupdated the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `$row` should be `$user`.

```php
@foreach ($users as $user)
<form action="/deleteEmployee/{{ $user->id }}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
</form>
@endforeach
```